# Unable to deploy Shiny app I don't understand the error?

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, shinyapps

Hello I am unable to deploy a shiny-app with the message below:

Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 7832248...DONE
Deploying bundle: 7170079 for application: 7832248 ...
Waiting for task: 1296973664
building: Parsing manifest
building: Building image: 8523304
building: Fetching packages
building: Installing packages
building: Installing files
building: Pushing image: 8523304
################################ Begin Task Log ################################
################################# End Task Log #################################
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 1296973665 error: Unhandled Exception: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 39887: invalid start byte
Execution halted

Can anybody help to understand the error and debug?